# How do I evaluate this integral by hand?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, problem-solving

TL;DR how do I evaluate $\int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{1}{\cos ^2(\theta )+1} \, d\theta$ by hand?

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Find the volume of the region defined by $x^2+xy+y^2+yz+z^2\le1$.
>
> (The answer is $\frac{4 \sqrt{2} \pi }{3}$)

I have tried several tactics. First of all, I rotated it $45^\circ$ in the $xz$ plane (converting all $x$ to $\frac{(x-z)}{\sqrt{2}}$ and all $z$ to $\frac{(x+z)}{\sqrt{2}}$ to obtain this:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+xy\sqrt{2}\le1$$

Now if I solve for y at the boundary I get

$$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{2} x\pm \sqrt{2} \sqrt{-x^2-2 z^2+2}\right)$$

And then I can integrate out the $y$ to get

$$\int _{-1}^1\int _{-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{1-z^2}}\sqrt{2}
   \sqrt{-x^2-2 z^2+2}\ dxdz$$

Which I can evaluate with Mathematica but not by hand [it does get the right answer in Mathematica, so I know I'm on the right track.]

I can then switch to polar coordinates in $x$ and $z$, yielding

$$\sqrt{2}  \int _0^{2 \pi }\int _0^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{2 \sin ^2(\theta )+\cos ^2(\theta
   )}}}r \sqrt{-2 r^2 \sin ^2(\theta )-r^2 \cos ^2(\theta )+2}drd\theta$$

This is relatively easy to integrate (the inner integral), so I get

$$\frac{4}{3} \int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{1}{\cos ^2(\theta )+1} \, d\theta$$

which I can't figure out how to evaluate by hand. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Do you know complex variables?

Comment: You do realize that TL;DR stands for "too long; didn't read", right?

Comment: @nbubis I give a long explanation of the problem below a short concise version for people who think this whole thing is too long to read

Comment: Placing a "TL;DR" statement at the beginning or end of a long-ish post is fairly typical forum/web style now...

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal no.

Comment: @JakobWeisblat: I already posted answer for your quetion which does not use complex variables.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I hadn't noticed it was you who had both commened and posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea at the beginning, but you didn't pursue it far enough. Use some linear algebra to rotate coordinates in $\Bbb R^3$ so that you get a straightforward equation for the ellipsoid: $\lambda_1 (x')^2 + \lambda_2 (y')^2 + \lambda_3 (z')^2 \le 1$. Now a straightforward application of the change of variables theorem (as was your instinct) will do it in one fell swoop.

Comment: Wow. This required so much less work - it's just 2 simple rotations. I had suspected I was doing too much.

Comment: Even better, find an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of the coefficient matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1/2&0\\1/2&1&1/2\\0&1/2&1\end{bmatrix}$. :)

Comment: Just for the record: the transformed ellipsoid is:        $${x^2 \over a^2}+{y^2 \over b^2}+{z^2 \over c^2}=1$$  

$ a^2 =  2 + \sqrt{2} $ , $ b^2 = 1 $ , $ c^2 =  2 - \sqrt{2} $ 

$$ abc = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}  \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2} $$

$ V = \frac{4\pi}{3} {abc} = \frac{4\pi}{3} \sqrt{2} $

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach. First evaluate the indefinte integral using the substitution $\theta=\arctan(u)$ which gives

> $$ I=\int \frac{d\theta}{1+\cos^2(\theta)} = \int \frac{du}{u^2+2} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$

Then, split the interval of integration as $[0,\pi/2]\cup[\pi/2,\pi]\cup [\pi,3\pi/2]\cup[3\pi/2,2\pi]$. In fact, you can write the integral as

> $$ I = 4\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{du}{u^2+2}= 4 \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{4}=\sqrt{2}\pi. $$

**Note:**

> $$ \cos^2(\tan^{-1}(u)) = \frac{1}{1+u^2}. $$